# Stop VoiceOver focussing on UILabel when text value changes

Tags: swift, xcode, uilabel, accessibility, voiceover

Context: I am currently trying to build the most accessible game on the app store, called Swordy Quest (https://apps.apple.com/us/app/swordy-quest-an-rpg-adventure/id1446641513)

Issue: When fighting VoiceOver will sometimes highlight the player's stats UILabel as the stats change.  But I won't to keep the focus on the currently selected button.  I use Apple's UIAccessibility.Notification.screenChanged to ensure focus.  I have also added in a dispatch async with a 0.1 second time delay to ensure this.  However, occasionally the updating of the stats text on the stats UILabel ends up taking focus.

Question: Is there a way to stop a certain UILabel from taking VoiceOver's focus when the value of its text changes.  Similar to .updatesFrequently accessibilityTrait but to never announce its changes, not just rarely announce its changes?

Comment: I didn't test this but a potential workaround is to maybe disable VoiceOver on that UILabel when updating it, and re-enable it after update. A bit of a hack but it might work 